# Print matched pattern and previous lines until a linebreak or a space, using sed or awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I want to print the "tmp and lines before until a line break", I'm a newbie to Unix.

EX: Input

```
AAA
CBH
VFh

GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
TMP
JHG

TFD
PI1
98A
TMP
TMP
765
UBS
```

My desired output should be like this

```
GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
TMP

TFD
PI1
98A
TMP
TMP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an `awk`:

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' 'match($0,".*TMP") { print substr($0,1,RLENGTH) }' file
GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
TMP

TFD
PI1
98A
TMP
TMP
```

This treats set of lines delimited by at least one empty line as a record.  If a record  matches the regular expression `.*TMP`, the bit after the match is removed and the rest of the record is printed.

The bit after the last occurrence of `TMP` is removed by matching the regular expression `.*TMP` against the current record, and then using `substr()` to print only the bit that matches that expression. The regular expression will match from the start of the record to the last `TMP` in it, and the `match()` function sets the variable `RLENGTH` to the length of that match.

You'll get a extra empty line at the end of the output since we're using a double newline as the output record separator.

---

If your file instead looks like

```
AAA
CBH
VFh

GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
tmp/some/path/here
JHG

TFD
PI1
98A
tmp/some/path/here
tmp/some/path/here
765
UBS
```

... and you'd want to do the same sort of transformation based on the lines starting with `tmp`, then modify the regular expression used with `match()` in the command so that it matches all the way to the newline character at the end of the "`tmp`-line":

```
$ awk -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' 'match($0,".*tmp[^\n]*") { print substr($0,1,RLENGTH) }' file
GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
tmp/some/path/here

TFD
PI1
98A
tmp/some/path/here
tmp/some/path/here
```

Note that I'm not 100% sure how `awk` is *supposed* to interpret `\n` inside a bracketed expression, but all the `awk` implementations that I have access to (OpenBSD `awk`, `mawk`, and GNE `awk`) seems to treat is as newline and *not* as the two separate characters `\` and `n`.

Comment: Thanks Kusal it works,but how do we print the last record also,my output last line  was truncated after tmp.

Comment: @RenganathanSeeralan I see no difference between my output and your desired output, except that I have an extra empty line at the end. If you want to remove that empty line at the very end, pipe the data through `sed '$d'`.

Comment: My record will be like this.

insert some date
.
.
.
.
tmp/some path
tmp/path...
...
...

insert some date
.
.
.
.
tmp/some path
tmp/path...

insert some date
.
.
.
.
tmp/some path
tmp/path...



Output only print up to the word tmp..remains are truncated.

EX Below:-

nsert some date
.
.
.
.
tmp/some path
tmp

insert some date
.
.
.
.
tmp/some path
tmp

insert some date
.
.
.
.
tmp/some path
tmp

Comment: @RenganathanSeeralan Whenever asking a question here, make sure that the data that you show is representative of the real data. Having further text after `TMP` (or `tmp`) will make a huge difference to any of the answers here. It's not even obvious that it's pathnames that we're dealing with when reading your question...

Comment: Thanks Kusal,Perfectly working..

Answer (score 1):

Just inverse the text and do a normal print from regex to regex and then again re-inverse to get the original order

```
 tac < file.txt | sed -n '/TMP/,/^$/p' | tac
```

Comment: Thanks Zohaib,without tac i am trying,since my text file has more than lakhs of record.

Comment: I guess `sed -n '/^$/,/TMP/p'` would work in that case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with matching up to first `TMP`. Empty `RS` will result in paragraph mode, where two or more consecutive `\n`  characters will be used as the record separator

```
$ # sub is used to remove everything after first occurrence of TMP
$ # return value of sub (0 if no match, 1 if match is found) determines
$ # if record should be printed or not
$ # use \nTMP\n to match only whole line
$ awk -v RS= 'sub(/TMP\n.*/, "TMP\n")' ip.txt
GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
TMP

TFD
PI1
98A
TMP
```

If you need till the last `TMP`, you can do it with `GNU awk` (because of `gensub`) or `perl`

```
$ # use \nTMP\n to match only whole line
$ # same as: perl -00 -ne 'print if s/.*TMP\n\K.*/\n/s' ip.txt
$ awk -v RS= '/TMP/{print gensub(/(.*TMP\n).*/, "\\1", 1)}' ip.txt
GFD
DFC
VGF
HGD
TMP

TFD
PI1
98A
TMP
TMP
```

Comment: or `match($0,/.*TMP/)` would also match til the last TMP as in [@kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/607784/133219).

Answer (score 0):

You had tagged with sed, and so we can do it as shewn. Note we are using GNU sed. As per my understanding you want to remove everything after the last line that begins with tmp (lowercase) in each paragraph of text file.
A paragraph is an island of nonempty line(s) separated by atleast one empty line from the next instance.

```
sed -e '
  /./{H;$!d;}
  x;/\ntmp/!d
  :chop
  /\ntmp[^\n]*$/!s/\n[^\n]*$//
  t chop
' file
```

Accumulate a paragraph in the hold. When we hit a boundary (empty line or eof) we start to examine the para. In case no tmp at the beginning of newline is to be seen we promptly delete this para.
Else, we start chopping off the lines from the end of para until we see the tmp line
Stop processing this para and print it.

With GNU awk, we operate in tge paragraph mode and set the input filed
separator to newline.
Start examining the fields from the end. Soon as we see a field beginning with tmp
We shrink the para upto that field and print
and be done with this paragraph.

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS= -v OFS='\n' '
  /(^|\n)tmp/ {
    for(i=NF; i; i--) {
      if ($i ~ /^tmp/) {
        NF=i; NF++; print; break
      }
    }
  }
' file
```

rindex will tell the position in a string of a substring from the end. So get the posituon of the last tmp by rindex abd use this position to get the position of the next nearest newline to it's right.

```
perl -p00e '
  s/.*//s,next unless /^tmp/m;
  s/\z/\n/;
  my $p = 1+rindex($_, "\ntmp");
  my $q = 1+index($_, "\n", $p);
  substr($_, $q) = "\n";
' file
```